# Datagrid passing x rows data to one cell of another datagrid on button WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a bigger program, but now I need to have DataGrid, which hold some variables and the last column must be button, that opens a new window with another datagrid. The problem is, that I need to bind all rows from that windowed datagrid to one for user invisible column in datagrid with button. One row in the Button DataGrid is one day of mechanic and the invisible column should hold all the material that he used that day. So is there anyway how to pass all rows in for example String variable?

XAML(Windowed DataGrid):

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ServisZL_new"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit" x:Class="ServisZL_new.MaterialAdd"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Anderes Material" Height="1200" Width="1000" WindowState="Maximized" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<ScrollViewer Background="#FFE5E5E5" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,-1" >
    <Grid x:Name="MainMaterial" Height="1169">
        <StackPanel>

            <DataGrid x:Name="dg_material" Margin="10,10,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="142"  Width="700" CanUserAddRows="True" AddingNewItem="DataGrid_AddingNewItem" CanUserDeleteRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PreviewKeyDown="dg_material_PreviewKeyDown">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Bezeichnung" x:Name="materialnazev">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Controls:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="ac_mat1" SelectedItem="{Binding Bezeichnung}" IsTextCompletionEnabled="True" FilterMode="Contains" MinimumPrefixLength="3" Loaded="ac_mat1_Loaded" SelectionChanged="ac_mat1_SelectionChanged" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Menge" Binding="{Binding Menge}" />
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Box" Binding="{Binding Box}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="SN" Binding="{Binding SN}" />
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Zylinder" x:Name="zylinder_name">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox x:Name="cb_zyl01" SelectedItem="{Binding Zylinder}">
                                    <ComboBoxItem Name="z00">--</ComboBoxItem>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Name="z01">Zylinder 1</ComboBoxItem>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Name="z02">Zylinder 2</ComboBoxItem>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Name="z03">Zylinder 3</ComboBoxItem>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Name="z04">Zylinder 4</ComboBoxItem>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Name="z05">Zylinder 5</ComboBoxItem>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Name="z06">Zylinder 6</ComboBoxItem>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Name="z07">Zylinder 7</ComboBoxItem>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Name="z08">Zylinder 8</ComboBoxItem>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Name="z09">Zylinder 9</ComboBoxItem>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Name="z10">Zylinder 10</ComboBoxItem>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Name="z11">Zylinder 11</ComboBoxItem>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Name="z12">Zylinder 12</ComboBoxItem>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Name="z13">Zylinder 13</ComboBoxItem>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Name="z14">Zylinder 14</ComboBoxItem>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Name="z15">Zylinder 15</ComboBoxItem>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Name="z16">Zylinder 16</ComboBoxItem>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Name="z17">Zylinder 17</ComboBoxItem>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Name="z18">Zylinder 18</ComboBoxItem>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Name="z19">Zylinder 19</ComboBoxItem>
                                    <ComboBoxItem Name="z20">Zylinder 20</ComboBoxItem>
                                </ComboBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
            <Button x:Name="button" Content="Speichern un schließen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,23,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Click="button_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

XAML(Button Datagrid):

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg_work" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="142" Margin="11,396,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="927" SelectionChanged="dg_work_SelectionChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PreviewKeyDown="dg_work_PreviewKeyDown" AddingNewItem="dg_work_AddingNewItem" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Ident}" />
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Datum">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Datum}" BorderThickness="0" SelectedDateChanged="DatePicker_SelectedDateChanged" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Arbaitszeit-Beginn" Binding="{Binding VonP}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Arbeitszeit-Ende" Binding="{Binding BisP}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rüstzeit" Binding="{Binding Rzeit}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Pause" Binding="{Binding Pzeit}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Übernachtung" Binding="{Binding Ubern}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Anfahrts-Zeit" Binding="{Binding ANZeit}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Anfahrts-Km" Binding="{Binding ANkm}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rückfahrts-Zeit" Binding="{Binding RFzeit}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rückfahrts-Km" Binding="{Binding RFkm}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Zusatzinfos" Binding="{Binding Zinfo}" />
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Material">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Button x:Name="button_add" Click="button_Click" Content="Material Anderse">                                                
                                        </Button>                                          
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

Code Behind(Windowed DataGrid):

```
 public partial class MaterialAdd : Window
{
    public MaterialAdd()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dg_material.ItemsSource = materialList;
    {
 private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UlozMaterial();
        predejtext();
        this.Close();
    }
 List<Material> predej = new List<Material>();
    public List<Material> materialList = new List<Material>();
    private void DataGrid_AddingNewItem(object sender, AddingNewItemEventArgs e)
    {           
        e.NewItem = new Material
        {
            Bezeichnung = "",
            Menge = "",
            Box = false,
            SN = "",
            Zylinder = ""               
        };              
    }

    private void ac_mat1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as AutoCompleteBox).ItemsSource = GlobalZL.list_zbozi;
    }

    private void dg_material_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var uiElement = e.OriginalSource as UIElement;
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter && uiElement != null)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            uiElement.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
        }
    }

    private void ac_mat1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //text = (sender as AutoCompleteBox).SelectedItem.ToString();           
    }

    public void predejtext()
    {
        string dg = dg_material.Items.ToString();
        foreach (DataGridRow row in dg_material.Items)
        {
            System.Data.DataRow MyRow = (System.Data.DataRow)row.Item;
            string value = MyRow["materialnazev"].ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(value);

        }
    }
}
```

Code Behind(Button DataGrid):

```
private void dg_work_AddingNewItem(object sender, AddingNewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        GlobalZL.dg_work_id += 1;
        e.NewItem = new Item_work
        {
            Ident = GlobalZL.dg_work_id,
            Datum = date,
            VonP = "7:00",
            BisP = "15:30",
            Rzeit = "",
            Pzeit = "",
            Ubern = "",
            ANZeit = "",
            ANkm = "",
            RFzeit = "",
            RFkm = "",
            Zinfo = "",

        };
    }
private void dg_work_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

            var uiElement = e.OriginalSource as UIElement;
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter && uiElement != null)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                uiElement.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
            }

    }
```

Comment: You might want to create a wrapper class with both the lists and pass on the wrapper class object from one datagrid to other.

Comment: How do you mean it can you give code example please?